# How to assert exception subtype and specific value/condition?

Tags: c#, nunit

With NUnit I can assert as follows:

```
Assert.That(() => MyTest(),
    Throws.Exception.TypeOf<MyException>()
        .With.Message.EqualTo("Whoopsie!"));
```

But I need to assert that:

1. The exception is a sub-type of `BaseException` (`IsSubTypeOf` below)
2. The exception carries a `401` value (`MatchesCondition` below)

Something like:

```
Assert.That(() => MyTest(),
    Throws.Exception.IsSubTypeOf<BaseException>()
        .With.Message.EqualTo("Whoopsie!")
        .And.MatchesCondition(exception => 
            ((ObjectResult)exception.ActionResult)
                .StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
```

I couldn't find such solution out-of-the-box in NUnit. Is there something like that, or must I implement a custom solution?

#### Conclusion

It took some time, but eventually found the out-of-the-box solution: `.InstanceOf<BaseException>()` and `.Matches<BaseException>(...)`:

```
Assert.That(() => MyTest(),
    Throws.Exception.InstanceOf<BaseException>()
        .With.Message.EqualTo("Whoopsie!")
        .And.Matches<BaseException>(exception => 
            ((ObjectResult)exception.ActionResult)
                .StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
```

And since `.Matches<BaseException>(...)` will anyway fail if the exception isn't a `BaseException`, it can be minimized even further to:

```
Assert.That(() => authenticator.Authenticate(),
    Throws.Exception.Matches<IbiActionResultException>(e =>
        ((ObjectResult)e.ActionResult)
            .StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
```

Comment: You can do `var exception = Assert.Catch<BaseException>(() => MyTest());` and then do more assertions on `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

For such a complicated test, I think it's cleaner to use multiple statements. You can make use of the fact that Assert.Throws is one of the few Assert methods that returns a value.

```
// This statement will fail if calling MyTest does not raise
// an exception of type BaseException. Otherwise, it will
// return the exception that was thrown.
var ex = Assert.Throws<BaseException>(() => MyTest());

// Check the message
Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("Whoopsie!"));

// Check the status code
Assert.That(ex.ActionResult.StatusCode,
    Is.EqualTo(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized));
```